# Error while read/ write to a csv file. Type mismatch between str and binary

Tags: python

I am very new to python (and programming in general). The code pasted below is for editing an existing csv. But I am getting an error. 
Error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Samsung Pc\Desktop\hungrypy1\hungry_data.py", line 34, in <module>
    writer.writeheader()
  File "C:\Users\Samsung Pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\csv.py", line 144, in writeheader
    self.writerow(header)
  File "C:\Users\Samsung Pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\csv.py", line 155, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "C:\Users\Samsung Pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tempfile.py", line 483, in func_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
[Finished in 0.5s]
```

I have tried to look for the answer and it seems to be a type mismatch from binary to string. I have tried to open the file as "r" instead of "rb" however is the same error. Please help. The code is as below.

```
import csv
import shutil
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

def get_length(file_path):
    with open("data.csv", "r") as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        reader_list = list(reader)
        print(reader_list)
        return len(reader_list)

def append_data(file_path, name, email):
    fieldnames = ['id', 'name', 'email'
    next_id = get_length(file_path)
    with open(file_path, "a", newline = '') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader() 
        writer.writerow({
                "id": next_id,
                "name": name,
                "email": email,
            })

append_data("data.csv", "Niraj", "test@test.com")

filename = "data.csv"
temp_file = NamedTemporaryFile(delete = False)

with open(filename, "r") as csvfile, temp_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    fieldnames = ['id','name','email','amount','sent']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(temp_file, fieldnames = fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()

    for row in reader:
        writer.writerow({
            "id" : row["id"],
            "name" : row["name"],
            "email": row["email"],
            "amount": "1234.34",
            "sent": "",
            })

#shutil.move(temp_file.name. filename)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You should not read and write to the same file at the same time:

```
with open(filename, "r") as csvfile, temp_file:
```

Even though you give this file two names, they are point to the same file in you disk, changeh it to:

```
 with open(filename, "r") as csvfile, open('temp_file.csv', 'w') as temp_file:
```

Answer (score 0):

what you're doing:

```
temp_file = NamedTemporaryFile(delete = False)
with open(filename, "r") as csvfile, temp_file:
```

The `, temp_file` part does strictly nothing. You have to open the file for writing...

and after that you're using `temp_file` as the output file handle, but it's actually a *string*, hence the message you're getting.

You want to do this:

```
with open(filename, "r") as csvfile, open(temp_file,"w",newline='') as outfile:
```

and then use `outfile`, not `temp_file`:

```
writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames = fieldnames)
```

Aside: don't use `writer.writeheader()`: the header is written anyway, you'll get it twice.